# Change fontsize of existing Label in Cocos2d-x

Tags: label, cocos2d-x

I am using Cocos2d-x 3.8.

I need to change the fontsize of a created TTF `Label`. Ie after it has been created, I need to change the fontsize. Not at creation. There is a way, right?

There is a `setSystemFontSize()`, however it seems that if you set it, the font itself changes from whatever font you initialized the label with, to the system font. I can't take that.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your case, but why you can't use `someLabel->setScale()` or action `ScaleTo` to a smooth increase labels ?
 It should monitor the AnchorPoint. If you have AnchorPoint set to `(0.5, 0.5)`, label will increase in all directions, if you have AnchorPoint set to `(0, 0)`, label will increase in top and right directions and so on.
I think, is the best way. You can create [ui::Text](http://cocos.sonarlearning.co.uk/docs/ui-elements-such-as-uibutto), which supports changing the font size

```
sometext->setFontSize(100);
```

But this method is not intended to change during program execution (it does not erase the text with the previous size of the font).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can change it by configuring ttfConfig for a Label, and try this method, setTTFConfig(ttfConfig).

```css
typedef struct _ttfConfig
{
    std::string fontFilePath;
    int fontSize;
    GlyphCollection glyphs;
    const char *customGlyphs;
    bool distanceFieldEnabled;
    int outlineSize;
}TTFConfig;
```